# Why does the size of one image differ on mobile but not on PC, when all images share the same class?

Tags: html, css

Why is the size of one of the images different from the other images on mobile but the same on PC?

All 3 images share the same class "IMGsize".
:
[Screenshot on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4FzT.jpg)
Here is a
[Screenshot on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG52z.jpg)
As you can see the third image gets bigger than the first two.

Here is a screenshot of the CSS code of the class:
["IMGsize"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay9Tn.png)

If needed, here is my implementation of the table I used to put the pictures and arrows in:
[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMRBL.png)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLw3t.png)

Some help would very much be appreciated as I'm trying to make my website more responsive. Please and thank you.

Comment: Please include code in your question, not in an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We would need to see a reproducible example to be able to try to figure out what's going on. Since I have to guess, maybe the item title word-wrapping is affecting the image height percentage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add object-fit property.

```
.IMGsize { 
    width:110%;
    height:90%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

check out different object-fit value on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I figured out what the problem was. The text was actually making the column larger therefore the picture was larger to fit the column.